# How do I get into a masters course in pure mathematics?

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics

My question is as stated in the title and to elaborate more:

I would like to know if there are any standardized international exams to enter a masters course in pure mathematics (besides GRE Math) and available for a scholarship simultaneously? (I'm a graduate in Automotive engineering, 23 years old and don't have a math degree yet).

I have completed 5 courses related to engineering mathematics during my tenure as a engineer.

I've been prepping only on math (topology, differential geometry, advanced calculus, real analysis, etc.) for the past 6 months and am almost ready for an entrance exam.

Can anyone offer me alternate options or solutions on how to go about this?

Comment: Also posted on [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/125323/8173)

Comment: Previously posted at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92440/how-do-i-get-into-a-masters-course-in-pure-mathematics-closed

Comment: Why do you want an international exam? Different countries have different processes, and it might be more useful to narrow down your research to universities to which you might be interested in joining.

Comment: Because it is tough for me to get into universities in India owing to the caste system reservation adopted by the government.The cut-off grade is higher for me and i have to compete for half the number of seats.Such reservation problems will surely not be followed in an international math qualification exam.And i am applying for a pure math masters course to get a feel of the lectures(i was an engineer before) and then progress onto research.2 German univs. suggested i start off as a bachelor's student in pure math(which is unnecessary given i've taken similar courses during engineering).

Comment: To my knowledge there are relative (compared to PhD programs) few masters programs in pure maths in the US. There may be more opportunities in Europe or Asia.

Comment: So, how did you do on the GRE Math exam?

Comment: Can you get some strong letters of recommendation?  I think that will help open many doors.

Answer (score 5):

There are no standardized international exams for mathematics. Strategies for applying for a masters in Maths is no different from any other program. The best, and possibly easiest, way to enhance your chances for acceptance is to find a means to self fund. Specifics on how to tailor an application are very country and program dependent.